# snort arp scan detection

Tags: rules, arp, snort, network-scan

Hi I am new to Snort and i simulated arp scan attack. I am trying to detect this attack in Snort. No preprocessors detected this attack so i wanted to write a rule for it. But i find out that snort rule does not support arp protocol.

This scan is sending arp request on all possible addresses from subnet 192.168.92.0/24 and waits for an answer which means that host is up. Is it possible to detect these attack using snort rules?

Here is the example of scan from wireshark.

[Arp Scan in wireshark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jz8iX.png)

Comment: Can you add what steps you've already taken to achieve this?

Comment: This scan was simulated using nmap -sn in kali linux. In snort documentation i find that snort rules support ip, tcp, udp and icmp but not arp, ospf and others which can be added later. So i cant write rule alert arp ... Snort can detect arp spoof using arp spoof preprocessor but not arp scan. But if he can detect arp spoof there must be the way to detect arp scan too.